# Removing rows from the top or end without any condition from MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am working on Data Analysis project. Sometimes, I come across files with say 80000 rows. But, for my work I just need a small portion like 5000. My analysis script only work till 5000  rows. That much portion is enough for me to analyze the pattern. So, I manually have to remove first 5000 rows and save it in another file. The problem I face is selecting and scrolling from row 1st till 5000 takes a long time and when am working on hundreds of file manually, it is not an efficient way.

So, what I am looking for is a script or selection formula which automatically select the rows that are in my range say row 1-5000. This will be very helpful for my work..

I am using MS EXCEL PROFESSIONAL PLUS 2010

Anyway know how to that or if someone has some script.. I will be thankful .

Answer (score 4):

Well, formulas in the excel sheet cannot make selections. A script surely could select a range you need for you, provided you define it first, but why would you use a script if you can use the built-in tools to do that?

For instance, if you type `1:5000` in the Name Box, located as indicated below:

[image]

Excel will make a selection of the first 5000 rows, without you having to select the first row, drag down somewhere in the middle of the file till the 5000th row.

After that you can cut/copy and paste to a new workbook, then come back to delete the rows if needed.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question you want to select the row then you can do this. On the home tab select menu "FIND & SELECT" the select GO TO give reference. Like this.

[image]

Comment: I do not understand. I want some function that select row 1- n without me dragging till nth row..